# Indexing PDF files with Symfony using Lucene

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, symfony1, apache-tika

I am a Symfony developer and my web server is Linux. I already use the sfLucene plugin.

**What is the simplest way of indexing PDF files for search on a Linux PHP server?**

1. [XPDF](http://www.kapustabrothers.com/2008/01/20/indexing-pdf-documents-with-zend_search_lucene/), installed [like this](http://www.kapustabrothers.com/2008/01/20/indexing-pdf-documents-with-zend_search_lucene/)
2. [Apache Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/) via the [SOLR sfLucene plugin branch](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfLucenePlugin/branches/1.2-Solr?rev=25426)
3. A 3rd option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from a Zend background, i generally recommend using Zend_Search_Lucene. The XPDF example is really straight forward and looks simple. XPDF is licenced as GPL - if that fits your need, go for #1!

ZF can easily be integrated within your Symfony projects, e.g. for a [Twitter Call](http://www.slideshare.net/skoop/integrating-symfony-and-zend-framework-phpbarcelona-2009).

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries for extracting text content from PDF. With any of these, you then need to create a lucene document with the content. The most useful ones will be those that already have lucene integration.

Apache PDFBox can [create a lucene](http://www.pdfbox.org/userguide/text_extraction.html#Lucene+Integration) document directly from PDF file. It will include PDF metadata fields as well as text content.